# How to set a default value for params.permit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to set a default value to one of my permited parameters.

I tried to do like they said http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
   @user = current_user
  end

  def create
    user_params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
                                                       user: {
                                                           avatar_link: '/assets/avatar-placeholder.png'
                                                   }
                                               })
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      redirect_to new_user_path
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar_link)
  end
end
```

But it doesn't seem to be working -- I'm getting `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError)` because of this part:

```
user_params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
                                              user: {
                                                  avatar_link: '/assets/avatar-placeholder.png'
                                              }
                                          })
```

How should I set a default value for my `params`?

UPD: I've tried to use @xlembouras solution, but now I have `rollback transaction`

```
def user_params
  defaults = {avatar_link: '/assets/avatar-placeholder.png'}
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar_link).reverse_merge!(defaults)
  puts params
end
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  has_secure_password
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  has_many :projects

  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, length: {maximum: 50}
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

Comment: what are the errors that cause the rollback? you should also provide the validation part of `User`

Comment: @xlembouras It's actually just `rollback transaction` in the console, nothing more.

Comment: rollback is the result of an error, either in the model, either on your db. you could add `@user.valid?; puts @user.errors` just before save, or set a debugger and see what happens.

Comment: I had an error in UsersController -- you're right

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can take advantage of the fact that `permit`'s output can be handled as a hash and just use a `reverse_merge`

```
def create
  user = User.new(user_params)
  ...
end

private

def user_params
  defaults = { name: 'A name' }
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :username, :email,
                               :password, :password_confirmation,
                               :avatar_link).reverse_merge(defaults)
end
```

Comment: Now I'm getting `rollback transaction`